# OpenLDAP does not validate TLS certificate

Tags: ssl, redhat, openldap

I am trying to run OpenLDAP (2.4.44 on RedHat 7.6) as a client against an existing LDAP server with TLS. This is working well - too well, actually. It looks to me as if OpenLDAP accepts any server certificate, instead of validating it against the CAs I provided.

Here is my ldap.conf file:

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap-2019.pem
TLS_REQCERT demand
URI ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com/
BASE ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com

# Some optimizations suggested by
# https://sourceforge.net/p/xcat/wiki/Setting_up_LDAP_in_xCAT/
set_cachesize 0 268435456 1
set_lg_regionmax 262144
set_lg_bsize 2097152
```

What I want to accomplish is of course that OpenLDAP validates the certificate for ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com against the list of CAs in TLS_CACERT.

But in reality, no matter what I put into the TLS_CACERT file, openldap seems to connect successfully, just as long as it is a valid PEM file.

What am I missing? Is there a second list of CAs that OpenLDAP consults? I also removed the CAs in /etc/pki/tls, just in case.

More details:

ldapsearch -x -uid=somename fails if I delete the file I specified in TLS_CACERT. It also fails if TLS_CACERT is not a valid PEM file. This is of course expected behavior when the client cannot validate a TLS certificate:

```
ldapsearch -x uid=somename
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

But if I put a completely nonsensical certificate into the TLS_CACERT file, ldapsearch will return a result as if the server's certificate was valid.

```
ldapsearch -x uid=somename
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: uid=somename
# requesting: ALL
#

# somename, People, mydomain.com
dn: uid=somename,ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com
...
```

For example, I tried using a certificate for www.google.com as a TLS_CACERT. I would have expected this connection to fail with the same "Can't contact LDAP server" error.

**Update:**

I found the cause but not the solution. OpenLDAP uses the certificate bundle in /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem . Renaming this file causes ldapsearch to behave as I expected, but of course that is not an acceptable solution since this is a systemwide file, not just for OpenLDAP.

So my new question is: how do I prevent OpenLDAP from using this file?

**Update 2:**

For clarification, this is on RedHat 7.6, and OpenLDAP 2.4.44. I assume that using the systemwide CA bundle is a RedHat modification to the stock OpenLDAP.

Comment: You haven't specified your server configuration, but this might be relevant: https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html

Comment: Thank you - I've been trying to work off that site, but it does not mention OpenLDAP accessing the systemwide CA list. Server configuration is RedHat 7.6, OpenLDAP 2.4.44 (which I'm sure has a lot of patches compared to stock openldap).